# Triple product $\displaystyle\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(k+n+m)^{\frac{(-1)^{k+m+n}}{k+m+n}}$

Tags: calculus, products, euler-mascheroni-constant

Prove that

$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(k+n+m)^{\frac{(-1)^{k+m+n}}{k+m+n}}=\frac{\mathbb{A}^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}} e^{\frac{1}{8}-(\frac{7}{12}+\gamma) \log 2+\frac{1}{2} \log ^{2} 2}}.$$

Here $\mathbb{A}$ is the [Glaisher-Kinkelin constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Glaisher-KinkelinConstant.html) and $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html). I found [this](https://www.tolaso.com.gr/documents/A%20collection%20of%20problems%20in%20Analysis.pdf) problem on this site at number $256$, there was a piece of advice just below:

> Currently I do not have a solution on this but the most straight
> forward idea is to actually try to find the number of ways $n$ can be
> written as a sum of three numbers and reduce the triple product into a
> single one.

The number of ways to represent $n$ as a sum of three natural terms is equal to $\frac{(n-1)(n-2)}{2}$, and then, obviously, take the logarithm. However, I get an unusually big logarithm term coefficient. May I be missing something?

Comment: Try to isolate just one product and ignoring others, do $$e^{\ln \prod}$$ and use logarithm properties to transform into an easier sum.

Comment: @Jacob What is fake inequality? This is the first time I've heard of such a thing.

Comment: @Cornifer For lack of a widely accepted term, I've used "fake equality" to indicate that the equality is not strictly true because a series diverges, but it does give a meaningful value to the divergent sum via regularization (c.f. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series). This is the same reason why we may write
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n \simeq -\frac{1}{12}$$

Comment: Using the naive approach,
$$\log\prod_{k=1}^\infty\prod_{n=1}^\infty\prod_{m=1}^\infty(k+n+m)^{\frac{(-1)^{k+n+m}}{k+n+m}}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+n+m}}{k+n+m}\log(k+n+m)\\ \simeq \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n(n^2-3n+2)}{2n}\log n\\ \simeq\frac{\eta'(-1)-3\eta'(0)+2\eta'(1)}{2}\\ =\log\left(\frac{\mathbb{A}^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}} e^{\frac{1}{8}-(\frac{7}{12}+\gamma) \log 2+\frac{1}{2} \log ^{2} 2}}\right)$$
where $\eta$ is the Dirichlet eta function, and $\simeq$ is fake equality due to divergent sums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $|x|<1$, $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^{k+n+m}}{k+n+m}\log(k+n+m) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-x)^n(n^2-3n+2)}{2n}\log n\\ = -\frac{f_{-1}(-x)-3f_0(-x)+2f_1(-x)}{2}$$
Where $f_s(x)=\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\text{Li}_s(x)$, and $\text{Li}_s(x)$ is the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Taking the limit as $x\rightarrow 1^{-}$, we get
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+n+m}}{k+n+m}\log(k+n+m)=\frac{\eta'(-1)-3\eta'(0)+2\eta'(1)}{2},$$
where $\eta(s)$ is the [Dirichlet Eta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function), and hence
$$\prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} \prod_{m=1}^{\infty}(k+n+m)^{\frac{(-1)^{k+m+n}}{k+m+n}}=\exp\left(\frac{\eta'(-1)-3\eta'(0)+2\eta'(1)}{2}\right)=\frac{\mathbb{A}^{\frac{3}{2}}}{\pi^{\frac{3}{4}} e^{\frac{1}{8}-(\frac{7}{12}+\gamma) \log 2+\frac{1}{2} \log ^{2} 2}}$$